# Convert Class.getEnumConstants to String

Tags: java, enums

This test case is to validate the generic enum generator. This generates the enums listed in an xml file.

Test case is to looping through each Enum class generated and verify if the enum constants matches the object generated from XML.

```
1. List of Enum constants from Enum:
Class<?> c = classLoader.loadClass("enum.java");
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(.getEnumConstants()));
[x,y,z]

2. List the Enum values from the Object generated from XML:
List<String> str1 = ["x","y","z"];
```

Now I wanted to compare 1 and 2. How to do?

I referenced https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/special/enumMembers.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

java.lang.Class.getEnumConstants() returns the elements of this enum class or null if this Class object does not represent an enum type. The methode .name() returns the name of a enum constant as a String. You can use it to compare to the Sting List.

First you convert the result into an ArrayList of type String

```
ArrayList<String> list1AsString = new ArrayList<>();
for(EnumName enum:list1){
 list1AsString.add(enum.name()); 
}
```

Then you can compare them.

```
list1AsString .equals(list2);
```

[Methode of Enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html)